# I'd like to create a table using data imported from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm unsure how to approach this. This is my first time working with JSON files and I'm just unsure where to start.

I'd like to take [this](http://api.opentracker.net/api/views/view_visits.jsp?login=demo@footprintlive.com&password=demo123&site=footprintlive.com&dataType=jsondatatable&jsoncallback=?&limit=10&timeZone=detect) and have a table that fills with the data. I am assuming that I use Javascript arrays, but I'm not certain where to go. I'm sorry that I basically have a lot of questions and nothing else, but again this is my first experience with JSON data.

Comment: Can you give us some idea of your experience level with general Javascript or jQuery? JSON is just a serialized Javascript object, but how you use it depends on a few different factors. Are you calling it remotely (via AJAX)? Is it going to be embedded in your page? Even posting a barebones example of the markup you want to end up with (after rendering) would be useful so we would know how to advise you.

Comment: can you also give an idea of how you want it laid out as in headers etc

Comment: for instance if you look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/simondavies/G7u3p/2/ it shows the top level sections then the inner values if set ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too difficult. JSON can look a lot more intimidating than it really is. You can use the jQuery get JSON method to make the call to your JSON file. You need to make sure that it is valid JSON. You can check this at http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Once you have a valid JSON file to work with you can make the call like this:

```
//call jQuery
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //call your JSON file, view.json is this file you're calling. in your case it is the URL to the JSON file
    jQuery.getJSON('view.json', function( data ){
        //once you've made the call you have access to the data
        theInfo = {
            // rename data.rows to just rows
            rows : data.rows
            //now if you type theInfo.rows into the console you will get 10 
            //you can now add this info to the DOM as you see fit
        };
    });
</script>
```

For templating JSON information into HTML I like handlebars.js, there are some good tutorials on YouTube and it just plain rocks, but you can add the info to the DOM using jQuery as well.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

[knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) should be the best choice for your thesis.

Comment: Assuming, of course, they need something with that much weight. jQuery could do just as nicely, depending on the OP's actual needs and skillset.

Comment: @mori57 honestly I believe knockout.js might be the easiest point to start considering OP never dealt with JSON before.
I agree that single link might not be best way of answer, but IMO the example code in the link might be the best to start with and I cannot come up with a better one... Considering the complexity of OP's origin JSON I think starting from some simpler stuff might be better.